# Can I embed Java applets in Windows applications using OLE?

Tags: java, com, applet, embed, ole

I have written a collection of useful Java applets. They are packaged in jar files. It would be great if they could be embedded into a Word document (for example). Now, I could write a full-fledged COM server and register DLLs, I suppose, but this seems overkill for something that web browsers (and the applet-tester provided with JDK and Eclipse) do without any of that hassle. **Is there an existing COM wrapper for Java applet embedding?**

The reason I want to embed in a Word file rather than a web page, is that ideally the document would be sent by email and edited. But with the applets still functioning within it. I appreciate there might be a few obstacles:

- I don't mind if it's not possible to specify parameters for the applets.
- I'm happy to rewrite the `JApplet`s as a pure java application (executable jar file) if it helps
- I don't mind if the jar has to be signed etc for security purposes

I couldn't find a solution to the problem on google, but equally I couldn't see any  reason why a solution doesn't exist!

Comment: The security implications are indeed rather gruesome. Will the recipient of the email have reason to trust your certificate?

Comment: well I thought this for a while, but then I thought again: with the appropriate "container" the security implications are no more than for a web browser, and one would presumably use the default java policy...

Comment: Signed applets, as far as I know, are allowed everything.